# Deleting columns from CSV by header name (or index)

Tags: php, csv, thephpleague

I am trying to modify uploaded CSV files using PHP. More specifically, I want to be able to drop/delete columns.

I have the below CSV file (+100k rows):

```
,news_headline,news_article,news_category
0,"50-year-old problem of biology solved by Artificial Intelligence"," DeepMind's AI system .....",technology
```

What I want to do, is to save a new copy of the CSV file, but only with the columns: `news_headline` and `news_category`.

This is my current setup

```php
use League\Csv\Reader;
use League\Csv\Writer;

//Read in current file.
$path = 'data.csv';
$reader = Reader::createFromPath($path);
$headers = ['news_headline', 'news_category'];
$records = $reader->getRecords($headers);

//Create a new file (override)
$writer = Writer::createFromPath($path);

//Insert new records
$writer->insertAll($records);
```

The above code outputs:

```
,news_headline
0,"50-year-old problem of biology solved by Artificial Intelligence"
```

Where I was expecting:

```
news_headline,news_category
"50-year-old problem of biology solved by Artificial Intelligence", Technology
```

Comment: Your example has two identical headers `news_headline`. Is this for real or is this just an error in the question?

Comment: @El_Vanja Good catch! That was an error :) Fixed

Comment: Also, what is the delimiter? Tab? And `|` is the enclosure or what?

Comment: @AbraCadaver It seems like the formatting I used for the CSV was confusing. I have updated that now. The delimiter is comma.

Comment: `$reader->getRecords($headers);` just overrides the headers from the file and doesn't act as a filter.

Comment: @NigelRen I see! Do you know of a way that I can modify the columns in the CSV?

Comment: Read the records in a loop and unset the columns you don't want.